# How to get Elastic Beanstalk to server compiled assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to get a Rails 3.2.x application to run in production but everytime I visit the deployed application it complains about assets not being compiled:

```
An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in home#index:

application.css isn't precompiled
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:142:in `digest_for'


-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

* URL       : http://some-server.elasticbeanstalk.com/
* Parameters: {"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index"}
* Rails root: /var/app/current
* Timestamp : 2013-01-17 17:22:55 UTC
```

However, when i consult the log files of my EB instance I see this as part of each deploy:

```
Script succeeded.
Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh
Output from script: /usr/bin/ruby1.9 /usr/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

I can run a local instance of Passenger in production mode and the assets are served fine. Does anyone have any insight on what might be going wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue w/deploying to AWS' Elastic Beanstalk.  Everything was working just fine until recently.  I tried reverting back to a previous commit but I'm still getting the "application.css isn't precompiled" 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your application by running the following command from your application root:

`touch tmp/restart.txt`

Fixed the issue for me.